# Asking many questions in one

Tags: support, stack-overflow, meta

My question here will get closed soon
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849045/which-version-of-asp-net-should-i-learn

because I asked too many questions in one and some people with power believe that asking what version of framework should I learn is "Subjective and Argumentative".

I don't want to ask 5 single questions, because I'm scared of being accused of spamming. What should I do? Is that question better for programmers or can it survive on stackoverflow?

P.S. Can I somehow re-post it to make it answerable? I know its "too localized", but I know that my country is like 2 years behind UK and US. So if they are not using .NET 4.0 than I should not even care about it.

Comment: ups, bad site. my bad, could you please migate my question to meta? I don't want to repost it, because I hear it can get you banned.

Comment: p.s. I voted to close it after reading first comments, because I was hoping it can be migrated to programmers. there should be a badge if you vote to close your own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ask your first question and get the answers to that. Then ask a follow up question.

Repeat until all of your questions are answered.

The answers to the each question may well change what questions you need to ask next, or even if you need to ask the next question at all - so asking them all in one go would be counter productive anyway.

Of course only ask your first question *on a particular site* if it meets the site's guidelines.

Comment: it turned out that you were wrong, it was first migrated to programmers and than closed :) but I got the answers, so I don't care :) http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/41760/which-version-of-net-should-i-learn-to-find-a-job

Comment: @01 - The general point holds - one question at a time.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in the comments to the [post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849045/which-version-of-asp-net-should-i-learn-to-find-a-job), the primary issue is not so much that you asked too many questions in one, it's that *all* of the questions you *did* ask were "Subjective and Argumentative". The close description that was given seems to fit your question pretty accurately to me:

> It's impossible to objectively answer this question; questions of this type are too open ended and usually lead to confrontation and argument.

No one can *objectively* tell you which languages you should learn, which languages are *better* than any other languages, or which languages/technologies are the most respected by possible employers. Not only is this information entirely subjective (meaning it depends on one's own personal feelings), but it's highly variable, both temporally and geographically. Any answers that might be given to the question would not be generally useful, and there's no *right* answer to the question.

And the [Frequently Asked Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow already provides a good explanation of what types of questions should *not* be asked:

> **What kind of questions should I not ask here?**
>
> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
>     -we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Comment: I still don't get it(those examples did not help). if you are for an example a java programmer and I ask you "should I learn struts or jsf to find a job?". The answer is that from your experience there is a lot more JSF jobs, but there are some maintaince jobs in struts. Why my questions are different?

Comment: is that questions ok for programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @01: I don't know. I spend very little time on Programmers, and I honestly have never understood the niche they've carved out for themselves. As with Stack Overflow, I suggest [reading the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq). And for what it's worth, your Java question is subjective as well. All of the same objections apply equally to it. I'd vote to close that question just as quickly (except that I don't follow the Java tags).

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, I think the first 3 and 5th can be grouped into one single question since they are all related to each other and users can answer them in one single answer.

The 4th question about dynamic programming should be a seperate question I feel.

But finally, the questions are too generic or subjective, since the answers will be finally given as opinions rather than the correct answers. In short, you will probably not get a **Correct** answer as such for such questions and thats the reason probably it was closed.